# React-Native FlatList render a zero state when data is empty

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to render an alternate component when the data is empty?  The only reason I would not just render the list or not render the list is that the `ListHeaderComponent` is necessary in both scenarios (`data.length` and `!data.length`)...

```
const data = []
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  data={data} // if empty or !data.length render <ZeroComponent/>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**UPDATE**
react-native recently added `ListEmptyComponent`

```js
const data = []
_listEmptyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            // any activity indicator or error component
        </View>
    )
}

<FlatList
    data={data}
    ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list} 
/>
```

```js
const data = []

renderFooter = () => {
  if (data.length != 0) return null;


  return (
    <View>
      // any activity indicator or error component
    </View>
   );
};

<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    data={data}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Didnt even realize there was a `ListFooterComponent`, this absolutely works!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: why not use ListEmptyComponent ?

Comment: `ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}` is not correct, it should be: `ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter()}`

Even better is to use `ListEmptyComponent ` like @julestruong said :)

Comment: At the time of writing my answer there is no ListEmptyComponent, I will try to edit my answer

Comment: `_listEmptyComponent` needs a _return_. I just added it in.

Answer (score 19):

There is a prop `ListEmptyComponent` which can do the job.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.showFilters()}
    ListEmptyComponent={this.showEmptyListView()}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

`{data.length > 0 ? <FlatList ... /> : <EmptyList />}`

Hope it helps

Comment: My mistake. The conditional render solution may worth

Comment: Also unfortunately, the list header is required in both scenarios so rendering Flatlist vs Other is not an option in this question.

Comment: Also onRefresh on flatlist  will not work, if there isn't any data at first.